# Google Material Design Icon - why file name doesn't name with actual size. How to use them in Android Studio without rename?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

I am finding difficult to understand why Google material design icon ( https://github.com/google/material-design-icons ) file name is suffixed like 24dp , 36dp etc, even though  there is already separate folder for each size  (i.e. drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi).

While  comparing the suffix with actual file size it doesn’t match. Filename with 48dp suffix may have actual size 192x192 , similarly 36dp file name will have actual size 144x144.

Issue I face while  using it, I have  to  manually remove  these suffix and copy it in android res drawable folder (i.e. drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi). Am not sure if this is right way to use them in Android Studio.

I know there must be some logic behind it but somehow I could not catch it. Hope someone  can explain this logic.

Comment: why do you want to remove the suffix? dp is not the same as px. 160dp = 160px = ~1inch on mdpi display. But most screen today are atleast xxhdpi. So to display higher density (clearer picture) on 1 inch across the screen, you need a 480px * 480px raster graphic. so 24dp you will get 15% of an inch, whereas 48dp you will get 30% of an inch when display on your device

Comment: Thanks @YouQi , Can you give me an example which files should be copied to android studio res drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi and  drawable-xxhdpi folder if I have to use ic_menu_black in my app ?

Comment: please see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DP` is not the same as `PX`. 160dp = 160px = ~1inch on mdpi screen. But most screen today are at least xxhdpi. So to display higher density (clearer picture) for 1 inch across the screen, you need a 480px * 480px raster graphic. so 24dp you will get 15% of an inch, whereas 48dp you will get 30% of an inch when display on your device. But for smaller devices which do not need the higher resolution picture, will instead fallback to use the smaller px file in the mdpi or hdpi directory.

Also, you should download your icons via here:

1. https://www.google.com/design/icons/
2. https://material.io/icons/

As for the example, google already have well defined material guideline here: https://material.google.com/style/icons.html

Let's use Launcher Icon as example, it's defined as 48dp. so you need a 48px x 48px in your mdpi folder. but if that is the only resource file, then when you install it on a phone like Nexus 5X, it will look very ugly, because you also need a 144px x 144px bitmap in your xxhdpi directory. This is why you always download an icon in a set of 5 with a _??dp postfix at the end of the icon.

Comment: Agree dp are not same as pixel still 2 points still open for me 1) what 48dp in file name represent ? I can see multiple files with same name ic_menu_black_48x but different size i.e. 192x192,96x96 etc.. 2) If I have to copy them in Android Studio which file should be copied to corresponding hdpi, ldpi drawable folder .

Comment: 48dp means you will always see it as a little above quarter of an inch on a device, no matter is a phone or tablet. The target phone will only read from one of the directory. if it's a xxxhdpi phone, it will take the picture from xxxhdpi directory, if it's an old and small resolution phone, it will take the picture from mdpi directory.

Comment: yes that I know, but question is, there are 2 files with same name but different size ..

Comment: do not expect to use dp image as scalable resource. just like you dont use a 128px source image and display in a img container with height and width of 512px on a webpage.

Comment: it's entirely up to you. button height is 48dp, do you need a 72dp image in a button? you dont! you want a smaller, maybe 24dp icon inside ur button to make it look good

Comment: not received complete answer that how to use it without rename, will post a separate question for that,  but at least come to know, I was wrongly comparing DP against pixels thats why file name was not matching